Getting Bad state: No element. Error thrown
Getting error "Bad state: No element. Error thrown" through Google Crash Analytics.  Here is the stack trace:
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError
Bad state: No element. Error thrown .
List.last (dart:core)
DisplacementEvent.localEndPosition (displacement_event.dart:97)
DisplacementEvent.localDelta (displacement_event.dart:118)
Road.onDragUpdate (road.dart:189)
MultiDragDispatcher.onDragUpdate (multi_drag_dispatcher.dart:81)
MultiDragDispatcher.handleDragUpdate (multi_drag_dispatcher.dart:124)
FlameDragAdapter.update (flame_drag_adapter.dart:30)
MultiDragPointerState._move (multidrag.dart:100)

GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (binding.dart:299)
I'm using flame: ^1.18.0
Here is my onDragUpdate code in a class called Road which extends SpriteComponent
@override
void onDragUpdate(DragUpdateEvent event) {
  if (isDraggable) {
    position += event.localDelta;
    dropX = position.x + 64;
    dropY = position.y + 64;
  }
}

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4037], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.10.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.92.2)
[√] Connected device (5 available)
[√] Network resources

Not sure where to start looking.  It looks like an issue in Dart Core?  Can anyone help?
As requested here is the full code for the Road component:
    import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flame/collisions.dart';
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/events.dart';
import 'package:umfths/audio/sounds.dart';
import 'package:umfths/flame/components/cell.dart';
import 'package:umfths/flame/components/gnome.dart';
import 'package:umfths/flame/components/path_stop.dart';
import 'package:umfths/flame/components/treasure.dart';
import 'package:umfths/flame/umfth_game.dart';
import 'package:umfths/flame/umfth_world.dart';

class Road extends SpriteComponent
    with
        CollisionCallbacks,
        DragCallbacks,
        HasGameRef<UmfthGame>,
        HasWorldReference<UmfthWorld> {
  Road(this.roadType) : super(anchor: Anchor.topLeft);

  RoadTypes roadType;

  double dropX = 0;
  double dropY = 0;
  double startX = 0;
  double startY = 0;
  double gravity = 2;
  Vector2 velocity = Vector2(0, 20);
  bool isDraggable = false;
  bool isWaiting = false;
  bool isInTube = false;
  bool isDragging = false;
  bool isAvailable = false;
  bool isSlowZone = false;
  bool isSpecial = false;
  int cellId = 0;
  String mess = '';

  final textChild = TextComponent(position: Vector2(1, 20), priority: 99);

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    add(textChild);

    add(RectangleHitbox(size: Vector2(128, 128), isSolid: true));

    if (roadType == RoadTypes.none) {
      roadType = gameRef.getRandomRoad();

      int special = Random().nextInt(20);

      if (special > 18) {
        isSpecial == true;
        setSpecial();
      }
    }

    String roadName = roadType.name;
    sprite =
        await Sprite.load('roads/$roadName.png', srcSize: Vector2(128, 128));

    /*  RoadBlock rbh = RoadBlock();
    RoadBlockVertical rbv = RoadBlockVertical();

    switch (roadType) {
      case RoadTypes.nw:
        add(rbh..position = Vector2(0, 124));
        add(rbv..position = Vector2(124, 0));
        break;
      case RoadTypes.ne:
        add(rbh..position = Vector2(0, 124));
        add(rbv..position = Vector2(0, 0));
        break;
      case RoadTypes.se:
        add(rbh..position = Vector2(0, 0));
        add(rbv..position = Vector2(0, 0));
        break;
      case RoadTypes.sw:
        add(rbh..position = Vector2(0, 0));
        add(rbv..position = Vector2(124, 0));
        break;
      case RoadTypes.horiz:
        add(rbh..position = Vector2(0, 0));
        RoadBlock rbh2 = RoadBlock();
        add(rbh2..position = Vector2(0, 124));
        break;

      case RoadTypes.vert:
        add(rbv..position = Vector2(0, 0));
        RoadBlockVertical rbv2 = RoadBlockVertical();
        add(rbv2..position = Vector2(124, 0));
        break;

      case RoadTypes.splitEast:
        add(rbv..position = Vector2(0, 0));
        break;
      case RoadTypes.splitWest:
        add(rbv..position = Vector2(124, 0));
        break;

      default:
    }

    if (roadType == RoadTypes.nw) {} */
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);

    if (isInTube == true) {
      // Sitting in glass emitter tube
      if (!isWaiting) {
        // Not waiting so let it drop down emitter tube
        velocity.y += gravity;
        position.y += velocity.y * dt;
      } else {
        // Has colided with another road in emitter so waiting
        // to drop down
        velocity.y = 0;
      }
    }

    //textChild.text = mess;
  }

  @override
  void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {
    super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);

    if (other is PathStop) {
      velocity.y = 0;
      isAvailable = true;
      velocity.y = 0;
      opacity = 1;
      isInTube = false;
      isWaiting = false;
      isDraggable = true;
    }
    if (!isWaiting) {
      if (other is Road) {
        isWaiting = true;
      }
    }

    if (other is Gnome && UmfthWorld.isDragging == false) {
      setOccupied(cellId, false, false);

      for (Road rd in UmfthWorld.gridRoads) {
        if (rd.cellId == cellId) {
          UmfthWorld.gridRoads.remove(rd);
          break;
        }
      }

      UmfthWorld.gridRoads.remove(this);

      parent!.remove(this);
       game.playAudio(SfxType.steal, false);
    }
  }

  @override
  void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
    super.onDragStart(event);
    if (isDraggable) {
      if (cellId > 0) {
        setOccupied(cellId, false, false);
      }

      priority = 1;
      isDragging = true;
      UmfthWorld.isDragging = true;
      velocity.y = 0;
    }
  }

  @override
  void onDragUpdate(DragUpdateEvent event) {
    /* if you are using DragUpdateEvent events, the devicePosition, canvasPosition, localPosition, and delta are deprecated as they are unclear.
    use xStartPosition to get the position at the start of the drag event ("from")
    use xEndPosition to get the position at the end of the drag event ("to")
    if you want the delta, use localDelta. it now already considers the camera zoom. no need to manually account for that
    now you keep receiving drag events for the same component even if the mouse leaves the component (breaking) */
    if (isDraggable) {
      position += event.localDelta;
      dropX = position.x + 64;
      dropY = position.y + 64;
      
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onDragEnd(DragEndEvent event) async {
    super.onDragEnd(event);
    isDragging = false;
    UmfthWorld.isDragging = false;
    if (isDraggable) {
      Cell? cb = getDroppedOn(dropX, dropY, this);

      if (cb != null) {
        if (cb.occupied == false) {
          setOccupied(cb.id, true, true);
          cellId = cb.id;
          cb.ignoreCollisions = true;
          x = cb.x;
          y = cb.y;

          velocity = Vector2(0, 0);
          opacity = 1;
          isDraggable = true;
          gravity = 0;
          isInTube = false;

          for (Road rd in UmfthWorld.gridRoads) {
            if (rd.cellId == cellId) {
              UmfthWorld.gridRoads.remove(rd);
              break;
            }
          }

          UmfthWorld.gridRoads.add(this);
        } else {
          //not a cell
          parent!.remove(this);
        }
      } else {
        // No empty cell found
        parent!.remove(this);
      }

      if (isAvailable == true) {
        // Removes first road from queue after user drags and drops
        gameRef.roadQueue.removeFirst();

        double firstY = 830;

        for (var w in gameRef.roadQueue) {
          // move each road in queue down by road height
          w.position.y = firstY;
          firstY -= 135;
        }

        // Set first road in queue properties
        // first is the one user can drag
        if (gameRef.roadQueue.isNotEmpty) {
          gameRef.roadQueue.first.isDraggable = true;
          gameRef.roadQueue.first.opacity = 1;
          gameRef.roadQueue.first.velocity.y = 0;
          gameRef.roadQueue.first.isInTube = false;
          gameRef.roadQueue.first.isWaiting = false;
          gameRef.roadQueue.first.isAvailable = true;
        }
        isAvailable = false;
      }
    }
  }

  setSlow() async {
    isSlowZone = true;
    SpriteComponent slow = SpriteComponent();
    slow.sprite =
        await Sprite.load('slow-down.png', srcSize: Vector2(128, 128));
    add(slow);
  }

  setSpecial() async {
    SpriteAnimationComponent s = Treasure();
    add(s
      ..priority = 100
      ..position = Vector2(32, 32));
  }

  Cell? getDroppedOn(x, y, road) {
    List<Cell> blocks = UmfthWorld.gridCells;
    for (final cell in blocks) {
      if (x >= cell.position.x &&
          x <= cell.position.x + 128 &&
          y >= cell.position.y &&
          y <= cell.position.y + 128) {
        if (!cell.occupied) {
          return cell;
        }
      }
    }
    //No cell
    List<Cell> cells = UmfthWorld.gridCells;
    for (final cell in cells) {
      if (cell.occupied == false) {
        return cell;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  Cell? getCell(x, y, road) {
    List<Cell> blocks = UmfthWorld.gridCells;
    for (final cell in blocks) {
      if (x >= cell.position.x &&
          x <= cell.position.x + 128 &&
          y >= cell.position.y &&
          y <= cell.position.y + 128) {
        return cell;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  void setOccupied(int id, bool val, bool ignore) {
    List<Cell> cells = UmfthWorld.gridCells;

    findById(obj) => obj.id == id;
    var result = cells.where(findById);

    Cell? c = result.isNotEmpty ? result.first : null;
    if (c != null) {
      c.occupied = val;
      c.ignoreCollisions = ignore;
    }
  }
}


Please provide code so we can help you...

What component is the Road added to, directly to the game, or to the world?
You're not calling any of the callback methods, or update manually anywhere right?
Note: it's not an issue with Dart core, it's trying to get the last element of an empty list in the Flame code, but it should be impossible for that list to be empty.

The Road is being added to the world and I'm not calling any callback methods manually.  Also,  I read somewhere, which I cant find again, that assigning the event.localdelta to a var first then using the var to set position would resolve the issue.  I have tired this and since have not received any more of these errors on the Road component. However,  I have received the same error on another component (Bomb) from the onDragUpdate callback (does not have the var assignment first).  The code for the Bomb  is almost identical as the Road component.

If you can provide a minimal reproducible example it would be very valuable to get this as an issue on the Flame issue tracker. I haven't heard of anyone else running into this.

Sorry but I cannot provide a example as I cannot get this error to occur on my devices.  I'm getting these errors reported from Firebase Crash analytics and it may be only occurring on certain devices?  The error report seems to indicate the error is occurring mostly from a Samsung phone (and a Gotron - FIH Foxconn what ever that is). There are many other devices not getting this error.    Do you think that assigning delta to a var first has any validity?

Since I assigned to var first I have not received any more errors from the Road component. Mind you it has been a short period of time since the change.  I will change the Bomb component to assign delta to var first and see if that stops the error from occurring on that component.  If any images from Firestore Crash analytics could help just let me know and I can send

I had a similar issue. I could solve it checking if the object is removed or being removed. Hope this helps you.
@override
void onDragUpdate(DragUpdateEvent event) {
    if(isRemoving || isRemoved)
        return;

    if (isDraggable) {
        position += event.localDelta;
        dropX = position.x + 64;
        dropY = position.y + 64;
    }
}

